# Octopus deploy-release running on all tenants

Tags: jenkins, octopus-deploy

My build is triggered thru Jenkins and does a Octo.exe deploy-release.  However, it is deploying to all the tenants that are specified for that Development environment.

I am not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Are you using the --tenant option to specify which tenant is to receive the release? From the wording of the question, it looks like you are surprised about the deployment behavior when the tenant is not specified. Reference here: https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/deploying-releases

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the argument like --tenant=VALUE in call of octo.exe

Make sure that you have multi-tenanted deployment enable in your project setting.